# How would you go about creating a lux meter for very low light (0.0001 to 1 lux)?

Tags: light, meter

I like to take pictures of the the sky in really dark places like Death Valley. To get an estimate of exposure times for the foreground I would like to measure the light intensity.

According to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux the light intensity can be between 0.0001 to 0.002 lux in these conditions. I can't find any commercially available light meters within that range. At least none that are affordable.

Does anybody know how to build a lux meter that can cover this range at an affordable price? It doesn't have to be calibrated. It's enough if I know that one place has half of the light another place has or similar.

Comment: The dynamic range it is not so high, so a logarithmic lux meter may be is the solution. A scintillator based one with photopic filters will do the work. There are some in the market -for laboratary use- costs around 1,000$ (head only). Try to make your own using parts from night vision equipments or gamma cameras.

Comment: Something tells me this could be done with a photoresistor or a PIN diode and the appropriate amplification, calibration, and processing. You could probably also use a photomultiplier tube and the appropriate filtering. Those count individual photons and you can find them on eBay.

Answer (score 1):

Astronomers, including amateur astronomers, are interested in the brightness of the night sky, and there are various inexpensive solutions.

There's a [project](http://amper.ped.muni.cz/light/lp_what_is.pdf) to monitor the night sky using EURO 100 light meters based on PV solar cells (only available to participants).

There's a [commercial device](http://unihedron.com/projects/sqm-l/) that is based on (I think) a Taos sensor. Around the same price. Calibrated in **visual magnitudes per square arcsecond** (logarithmic).

[image]

Even an [iPhone app](http://www.darkskymeter.com/faq/) that uses the camera (not sure how well that works).